# Web scraping image inside canvas

Tags: python, image, canvas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am web scraping a page where with various numbers appears also images of small price charts.

If I click on this images inside the browser I can save that chart as a `.png` image.

When I look at the source code that element looks like this when inspected:

```
<div class="performance_2d_sparkline graph ng-isolate-scope ng-scope" x-data-percent-change-day="ticker.pct_chge_1D" x-sparkline="watchlistData.sparklineData[ticker.ticker]">
  <span class="inlinesparkline ng-binding">
    <canvas width="100" height="40" style="display: inline-block; width: 100px; height: 40px; vertical-align: top;">
    </canvas>
  </span>
</div>
```

Is there any way I can save through web scraping the same images that I can save manually through the browser?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are using Selenium for your web scraping, you can get the canvas element and save it to the image file using the following code snippet:

```
# get the base64 representation of the canvas image (the part substring(21) is for removing the padding "data:image/png;base64")
base64_image = driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector('.inlinesparkline canvas').toDataURL('image/png').substring(21);")

# decode the base64 image
output_image = base64.b64decode(base64_image)

# save to the output image
with open("image.png", 'wb') as f:
   f.write(output_image)
```

Comment: thanks, but I am really struggling to understand where I should modify with my details. where to enter the tag name in which the image resides? I manage to open the page with Selenium but not sure on how to use your code  -- WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Cannot read property 'toDataURL' of null --

Comment: It does work is just that if I launch your code at the same time I am launching the code that login in to the page, your code execute too quickly before the page opened. is there a 'sleep' command? there is also the issue that I have many tags 'inlinesparkline canvas' and in that case it does not work

Comment: it does only save the first canvas not the others

Comment: I tried with 'document.querySelectorAll' but it says is not a function

Comment: sorted with this: for i in range(0,3):
    base64_image = browser.execute_script("var i = {a}; return document.querySelectorAll('.inlinesparkline canvas')[i].toDataURL('image/png').substring(21);".format(a=i))

    # decode the base64 image
    output_image = base64.b64decode(base64_image)

    # save to the output image
    with open("image{a}.png".format(a=i), 'wb') as f:
       f.write(output_image)